# Copper pyrite representation

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metallurgy

What is the oxidation state of iron in $\ce{CuFeS2}$? And also could you please tell it's proper representation: $\ce{Cu2S.FeS.FeS2}$ or $\ce{Cu(I)FeS2}$?

Comment: $\ce{Cu2S.FeS.FeS2}$ and $\ce{CuFeS2}$ are fine, but $\ce{Cu(I)FeS2}$ is wrong. Oxidation state in parentheses used in written names; if you want to denote monovalent copper, then $\ce{Cu^IFeS2}$

Comment: Can you please also comment on their oxidation state ie. Is  iron in +2 and copper in +1?

Comment: But you've already answered this part by typing $\ce{Cu^I}$, haven't you? :)  The structure contains  $\ce{Cu+}$ and $\ce{Fe^3+}$ cations.

Comment: In the formula Cu2S.FeS.FeS2, the 1st iron is in +2 and the second one is also in +2 by me, ie it is polysulphide ion (  S2 (2- ) ion ), so their avg will also be 2 right?

Comment: No. $\ce{Cu2S.FeS.FeS2}$ is just a convenient representation, nothing else. In reality the cubic  structure consists of array of vertex-linked $\ce{CuS4}$ and $\ce{FeS4}$ tetrahedra, that's it. There is no separate standalone metal sulfides as one would imagine.

Comment: No prob, there were debates in the past whether it's iron(II) or iron(III), but these days Mössbauer and photoelectron-emission spectroscopies alongside with magnetic measurements suggest it's iron(III).

Comment: If you are really interested in details, there is an [open-access article on what's going on with copper and iron in chalcopyrites](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1511/1511.04753.pdf).